# Controls within group boxes being hidden when moved out of the group box

Tags: c#, .net, controls

I was just wondering, I have a button within a TabControl and whenever I try and move it outside of the TabPage it becomes hidden as if it were underneath everything...

I was wanting to implement a way to change the position of this button but the fact that it becomes invisible meant I tried dragging out of the TabControl and just changing its x/y position to make it look like its inside it, however now if i swap to a different tab in the TabControl it is still visible since it's doesn't belong to the TabControl anymore.

Is there a property of the button that would allow me to change this behavior so I can put and take it out of the tabs ability to hide it when swtiching to other tabs?

edit --
The button seems to go invisible when moved outside of a groupbox within the tab not the tab itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing which parent it belonged to did the trick